# Can I validate the presence of acts_as_taggable_on tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, acts-as-taggable-on

Yea I have a model with `acts_as_taggable_on :styles`, my styles taggings are passed in from an array of check boxes:

```
<% styles.each do |style|%>
  <%= check_box("tattoo", "style_list", {:multiple => true}, style, nil) %> <span class="tatto_style"><%= style %></span>
<% end %>
```

But I want to make sure that a user checks at least one style.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your model:

```
validates_presence_of :style_list
```

OR

```
validate :required_info

private

def required_info
  if( style_list.empty? ) 
    errors.add_to_base "Please choose a style"
  end
end
```